# In JasperReports, how do I include a "blank" row that will remain on xlsx export?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I am experiencing a data format issue when exporting to xlsx from JasperReports Server (v 6.3.0, build 20160621_1840). Consider a report that contains the following:

1. some header information related to report parameters that were selected
2. a blank row separating the header from the data
3. a table that contains the data that is returned given the selected parameters

The desired behavior is that, on xlsx export, a user can click on a single data cell and click sort (or hit ctrl+t to create a data table, etc.) without Excel automatically trying to include header information as part of the sort (data table, etc.). The problem is that on xlsx export, Jasper refuses to truly create a "blank" row, which means that the operation extends to all report bands, not just the data band:

[image: The operation extends to all report bands, not just the data band.]

As you can see, if I hit ctrl+t while in a single data cell, the selection extends to #1 and #2, but the desired behavior is to have it only include #3.

I have tried the following:

- adding extra space below the header information
- putting an empty text field into that area
- explicitly setting the value of that text field to null
- checking the "Blank When NULL" option
- adding an empty frame below the header information
- putting an empty text field into that frame, etc.
- trying all of the above in a new band that's between the header and the data bands
- playing with the "Print When Expression" by setting it to TRUE()

In the above scenarios, on xlsx export, either the added row (#2) does not appear, or it does appear but is not "blank", as below.

[image: Blank row containing an empty cell that is not actually "blank"]

Presumably, it contains an empty string. Simply entering and exiting the cell makes it empty.

Note that export from Jaspersoft Studio functions as expected (mostly). As mentioned, the question is about preserving blank rows on export after deployment to JasperReports Server. In particular, the issue is with xlsx export, but not with xls export.

A simplified version of the report is below (server info is stripped) that demonstrates some of the different strategies I tried to create blank rows around the data. Here is a table that shows what happens when the report below is exported from JasperReports Server:

```
export format | empty header row? | empty footer row?
=====================================================
     xls      |        yes        |        no        
     xlsx     |        no         |        no
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-17T09:49:04 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Single_Amount" pageWidth="600" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="600" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="2c25db5f-6fb0-41a2-8a3a-894bafd6d9d4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#8FAFCC">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CFDBE6">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#8A8383"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E3EBF2"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="db" uuid="ac48b023-08c7-4a89-9bbd-551911707109">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select 'John' "First Name", 'Smith' "Last Name", '' "Organization Name" from dual]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="First Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Last Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Organization Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'John' "First Name", 'Smith' "Last Name", '' "Organization Name" from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="First Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Last Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Organization Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="45">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="45" uuid="5134c566-280b-45b1-bab7-c44956531a4f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="600" height="15" uuid="8307c6e8-567d-466f-8e7f-1c85c5acee3d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Transactions involving at least 25.00 USD"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="15" width="200" height="15" uuid="2b678b6b-4553-497f-aa2d-ef886011c7f9">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="61">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="61" uuid="7ed23a83-5028-42ce-9cb0-10a2e4ad5d98">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="db" uuid="595295a2-96d8-4b04-a595-95844237815b">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="8c6f9d1f-c20e-4aaf-9a04-1a66e5adf7dd">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="40c088be-aac3-41f2-9dce-d0e4741d306a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="df14df5e-df01-4b69-811e-895d5846eb80">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{First Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="17860d95-195a-4303-b64b-79ea1180e369">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="22c004ba-6b97-4979-a33c-bbe565df3868"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="be9b6c0d-dc9b-43f0-b17d-1bf7a24af3e6">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Last Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="eb8ac0d4-1b63-46f9-84de-cd5d2e50aabb">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="db802f9a-9d3e-4a73-a8a8-23aa2c486ea7"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Organization Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="28e8791f-9fc7-41e9-b5d7-b0d6c3e640ec">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Organization Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="422" height="15" uuid="53446078-6906-48c0-a3b4-d538e542a3ff">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Could you please paste your jrxml as well ? So that it will help us to understand more clearly?

Comment: If you just want to include auto filter on column then you can use jasper property. Right click on table header -> Choose XLS tags -> Auto Filter -> Start. In this case you can directly add auto filter functionality. I hope this helps.

Comment: While not the answer to the question, this is a useful comment. There are some cases where autofiltering helps.